# Second row as column headers using DT datatable in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I have an output to be rendered in a shiny app using DT::datatable.

The output which currently looks like this and I want to use the second row as the column headers:

```
tab1:
          V1      V2      V3      V4      V5      V6      V7      V8    
Month   Apr-17  May-17  Jun-17  Jul-17  Aug-17  Sep-17  Oct-17  Nov-17  
aaa     116.719 120.404 120.26  123.431 117.327 110.742 114.811 117.34  
bbb     76.118  75.976  76.215  76.134  77.19   78.519  78.258  74.522
```

So when I want to use the row month as column headers I do the following:

```
   app1 <-reactive({ tab1()%>% .[-1,]})
```

And then I render it using datatable

```
 output$op1 <-renderDataTable({
    app1()
  })
```

I get the following output :

```
        V1    V2      V3      V4      V5      V6      V7      V8    
aaa     116.719 120.404 120.26  123.431 117.327 110.742 114.811 117.34  
bbb     76.118  75.976  76.215  76.134  77.19   78.519  78.258  74.522
```

How do I replace the v1,v2 by month names .Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `set_names` on the data frame with the first row, and then remove the first row:

```
df %>% set_names(unlist(.[1,])) %>% tail(-1) # or .[-1,]
#     Apr-17  May-17 Jun-17  Jul-17  Aug-17  Sep-17  Oct-17 Nov-17
#aaa 116.719 120.404 120.26 123.431 117.327 110.742 114.811 117.34
#bbb  76.118  75.976 76.215  76.134   77.19  78.519  78.258 74.522
```

And in your case: `reactive({ tab1() %>% set_names(unlist(.[1,])) %>% tail(-1) })`

Comment: I get this error when I do this `nm must be NULL or a character vector the same length as x`

Comment: `tab1() %>% set_names({print(length(.)); print(length(unlist(.[1,]))); unlist(.[1,])}) %>% tail(-1)` I am not sure what is happening. Can you add these prints in your method, and check whether the two prints give the same number?

Comment: works fine. While transposing it was being converted to a matrix and not a df. Thank you.